# Partially replace video stream while preserving audio stream

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

Consider a video file with one video and one audio stream. I want to replace the video stream partially while preserving the original audio stream.

With partially I mean to replace certain seconds within the original video stream with another video stream of the corresponding length (either specifying the time or frame span)
Additionally I want to replace multiple parts of the original video stream.

Would it be possible with an `ffmpeg` one-liner? Otherwise what would be the best procedure to follow? [Extract audio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27413824/6942816), [cut down everything in small video chunks](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video/141343#141343), [concatenate them together](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec) and [add the original audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783474/6942816)?

Exact timing is not relevant at first hand.